# Custom Cell Tag does not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have the custom cell and each cell has one label and one textfield. Whenever I edit textfield in any of the cell, it always returns the tag id=0 (senderTextField.Tag), even though I edit second or third cell's text field.

```
if (indexPath.Row == 0) {
      cell.iLabel.Text = "AB Name";
      cell.iField.Text = ab [0].ab;
      cell.Tag = 0;
 } 
else if (indexPath.Row == 1) {
      cell.iLabel.Text = "CD Name";
      cell.iField.Text = ab [0].cd;
      cell.Tag = 1;
} 
else if (indexPath.Row == 2) {
      cell.iLabel.Text = "EF Name";
      cell.iField.Text = ab[0].ef;
      cell.Tag = 2;
}
```

**Custom Cell**

```
iField.EditingDidEnd += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    UITextField senderTextField = (UITextField)sender; 
    Console.WriteLine ("Tag id is : {0}",senderTextField.Tag);
    tableView.ReloadData();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells and UITextFields are separate views, which have separate tags. You'll have to set the tag of the textfield, not the cell, if you want to look it up later for some reason.